# Expandable UITableview cell using NSDictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my code:

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *sectionTitleArray;
    NSMutableArray *arrayForBool;

    NSArray *aboutStep0neArray;
    NSArray *profileArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tablevw;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tablevw.delegate = self;
    _tablevw.dataSource = self;

    arrayForBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    sectionTitleArray = @[ @{@"text": @"About Step0ne"},
                           @{@"text": @"Profile"},
                           @{@"text": @"Matches"},
                           @{@"text": @"Messages"},
                           @{@"text": @"Photos"},
                           @{@"text": @"Settings"},
                           @{@"text": @"Privacy"},
                           @{@"text": @"Reporting issues"},
                          ];

    aboutStep0neArray = @[ @{@"text1": @"stepone1"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone2"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone3"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone4"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone5"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone6"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone7"},
                           @{@"text1": @"stepone8"},
                         ];

    profileArray = @[ @{@"text2": @"profile1"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile2"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile3"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile4"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile5"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile6"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile7"},
                      @{@"text2": @"profile8"},
                    ];



    for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++)
    {
        [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

    }

}

#pragma mark:- UITableView Delegate and Datasource Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
    {
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return [aboutStep0neArray count];
        }
        else if (section == 1)
        {
            return [profileArray count];
        }
     }
     return 1;
 }  

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    BOOL manyCells = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]boolValue];

    if (!manyCells)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[aboutStep0neArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text1"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [[profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text2"];
        } 
    }
    return cell;
}


 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
/*************** Close the section, once the data is selected ***********************************/
    [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber
  numberWithBool:NO]];

    [_tablevw reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue])
    {
        return 40;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

#pragma mark - Creating View for TableView Section

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;
    UILabel *viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 0, _tablevw.frame.size.width-10,
  40)];
    viewLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    viewLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    viewLabel.text=[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];

    /********** Add a custom Separator with Section view *******************/
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 40, _tablevw.frame.size.width-35, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [sectionView addSubview:separatorLineView];

    /********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
  action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];

    [sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    return  sectionView; 
 }

#pragma mark - Table header gesture tapped

- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        for (int i=0; i<[sectionTitleArray count]; i++)
        {
            if (indexPath.section==i)
            {
                [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!collapsed]];
            }
        }
        [_tablevw reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:gestureRecognizer.view.tag]
  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

     }

     [_tablevw reloadData];
}
```

First in tableview `sectionTitleArray` objects should display.After that when I click the `About Stepone` row it should expand with `aboutSteponeArray` objects and after clicking again it should collapse.Same incase of `profileArray` too. `AboutSteponeArray` and `profileArray` are the sections of the `sectionTitleArray`.

When I run my code I'm getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9cfb4bf880' error.

Comment: why down voted for my post.Let me know my mistake please.

Comment: Try removing extra "`,`" from last object of each array like : `@{@"text": @"Reporting issues"},` and run the code again

Comment: Your question was poorly formatted, that is why someone down-voted it.

Comment: because the last element does'nt need "`,`".

Comment: If i removed " , " as you said am getting error.

Comment: The error looks like you are passing a dictionary to a method that expects a string (perhaps when setting the title of a table view cell?). Your code doesn't  seem to call the offending method (`rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`) but most likely `UILabel` does, internally, in order to display its text.

Comment: Make sure your logic is in sync with the structure of your arrays/dicitonaries.

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [[aboutStep0neArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text1"];

Comment: i edited the above line with

Comment: cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" [aboutStep0neArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"text1"];

Comment: am not getting output.Please can you guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays are incorrectly instanciated : don't add a comma `,` after the last element in each array

```
sectionTitleArray = @[ @{@"text": @"About Step0ne"},
                       @{@"text": @"Profile"},
                       @{@"text": @"Matches"},
                       @{@"text": @"Messages"},
                       @{@"text": @"Photos"},
                       @{@"text": @"Settings"},
                       @{@"text": @"Privacy"},
                       @{@"text": @"Reporting issues"}
                     ];

aboutStep0neArray = @[ @{@"text1": @"stepone1"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone2"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone3"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone4"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone5"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone6"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone7"},
                       @{@"text1": @"stepone8"}
                     ];

profileArray = @[ @{@"text2": @"profile1"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile2"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile3"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile4"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile5"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile6"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile7"},
                  @{@"text2": @"profile8"}
                ];
```

**EDIT** :

The source of your problem is in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` at the following line :

```
viewLabel.text=[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];
```

Since each element of your `sectionTitleArray` is a `NSDictionnary`, you are then assigning a `NSDictionnay` to a the label tetxt attribute which is `NSString` typed.

Since all the keys in all dictionnaries stored in `sectionTitleArray` are `@"text"` , replace with the following :

```
viewLabel.text= [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: Hi @Niko i removed "," for all arrays. Still am getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: error in my code

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code & found few issues. Here is the corrected code:

First Removed Key Values from Array:

```
sectionTitleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"About Step0ne", @"Profile", @"Matches", @"Messages", @"Photos", @"Settings", @"Privacy", @"Reporting issues", nil];
aboutStep0neArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"stepone1", @"stepone2", @"stepone3", @"stepone4", @"stepone5", @"stepone6", @"stepone7", @"stepone8", nil];
profileArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"profile1", @"profile2", @"profile3", @"profile4", @"profile5", @"profile6", @"profile7", @"profile8", nil];
```

**Reason:**
You have given common keys to all objects than why its needed to give keys. That was creating an issue so removed.

**Than:**
In Tableview method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    BOOL manyCells = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
    if (!manyCells) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    } else {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [aboutStep0neArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This is the only change i have done & tested. It worked fine for me.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: yes,But i need to store arrays in the form  of dictionary.And need to retrieve data as objectForKey @mayur

Comment: @srinitha the answer i posted by watching current scenario of your code & i found that there was no use of Key values & it was giving crash issue.